# Remove duplicated elements from a List<String>

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I would like to remove the duplicate elements from a List. Some elements of the list looks like this:

```
Book  23
Book  22
Book  19
Notebook 22
Notebook 19
Pen 23
Pen 22
Pen 19
```

To get rid of duplicate elements i've done this:

```
List<String> nodup = dup.Distinct().ToList();
```

I would like to keep in the list just

```
Book 23
Notebook 22
Pen 23
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: How do the others qualify as a duplicate ?

Comment: So you basically want only a single element of the item type, regardless of the number?

Comment: This question is very unclear, and I think you need to clarify exactly what it is you want

Comment: i modified it ! Is it clear enough now ?

Comment: Certainly clearer than it was :)  You still haven't actually said that for each group of item names you want the one with the highest number tho (which you seem to have indicated in one of the comments you made)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LINQ` in combination with some `String` operations to group all your itemy by name and `MAX(Number)`:

```
var q = from str in list
        let Parts = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        let item = Parts[ 0 ]
        let num = int.Parse(Parts[ 1 ])
        group new  { Name = item, Number = num } by item into Grp
        select new {
            Name  = Grp.Key,
            Value = Grp.Max(i => i.Number).ToString()
        };

var highestGroups = q.Select(g => 
    String.Format("{0} {1}", g.Name, g.Value)).ToList();
```

(Same as Reed's approach but in query syntax which is better readable to my mind)

**Edit**: I cannot reproduce your comment that it does not work, here is sample data:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
list.Add("Book  23");
list.Add("Book  22");
list.Add("Book 19");
list.Add("Notebook  23");
list.Add("Notebook  22");
list.Add("Notebook  19");
list.Add("Pen  23");
list.Add("Pen  22");
list.Add("Pen  19");
list.Add("sheet 3");

var q = from str in list
        let Parts = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        let item = Parts[ 0 ]
        let num = int.Parse(Parts[ 1 ])
        group new  { Name = item, Number = num } by item into Grp
        select new {
            Name  = Grp.Key,
            Value = Grp.Max(i => i.Number).ToString()
        };

var highestGroups = q.Select(g => String.Format("{0} {1}", g.Name, g.Value));
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, highestGroups));
```

The result:

```
Book 23
Notebook 23
Pen 23
sheet 3
```

Comment: It seems to work for string but it copies the number from a string to a different one .

Comment: @Emil: You've lost me there. Only the `ToList()` at the end materializes the query. Can you explain your comment? If you don't want to get the number's String representation you could change `Grp.Max(i => i.Number).ToString()` to `Grp.Max(i => i.Number)`. It would still work because of the implicit converison in `String.Format` at the end.

Comment: i mean in the list i have ( books 22 , notebook 21 , pen 10) if i add another item (sheet 3) to the list the max number of the list would be copied to the new item . result: ( books 22 , notebook 21 , pen 10 , sheet 22)

Comment: yes i've tried it! it does excactly what i've said in previous comment.

Comment: @Emil: See my last edit where i've added your sample data and the output.

Answer (score 3):

you can do someting like

```
string firstElement = dup.Distinct().ToList().First();
```

and add it to another list if you want.

Comment: In the question i've said that some elements are like that !

Comment: @EmilDumbazu actually, you haven't said a great deal about *anything* in the question!

Comment: Hey Emil, let's stay polite. Dipesh's solution actually comes up with an equivalent result too. Try answering the questions in the comments, it will help for sure to find a better fitting solution.

Answer (score 3):

It's not 100% clear what you want here - however...

If you want to keep the "largest" number in the list, you could do:

```
List<string> noDup = dup.Select(s => s.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(p => new { Name=p[0], Val=int.Parse(p[1]) })
        .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
        .Select(g => string.Join(" ", g.Key, g.Max().ToString()))
        .ToList();
```

This would transform the `List<string>` by parsing the numeric portion into a number, taking the max per item, and creating the output string as you have specified.

Comment: @EmilDumbazu SOrry - had a typo. Should be "p[1]" - fixed now.

Comment: First of all Parse expects a string as parameter and after i modify  .toString() it throws me this: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You understood my question , i would like to keep the string with the biggest number!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add a custom comparer as a parameter, as you can see in [the example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx).

In this example I assumed `Foo` is a class with two members.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Foo>()
        {
            new Foo("Book", 23),
            new Foo("Book", 22),
            new Foo("Book", 19)
        };

        foreach(var element in list.Distinct(new Comparer()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element.Type + " " + element.Value);
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string type, int value)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public string Type { get; private set; }

    public int Value { get; private set; }
}

public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        if(x == null || y == null)
            return x == y;
        else
            return x.Type == y.Type;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
    {
        return obj.Type.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This works on an `IList`, assuming that we want **the first item each**, not the one with the highest number. Be careful with different collection types (like `ICollection` or `IEnumerable`), as they do not guarantee you any order. Therefore any of the `Foo`s may remain after the `Distinct`.

You could also override both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` of `Foo` instead of using a custom `IEqualityComparer`. However, I would **not actually recommend this** for a local distinct. Consumers of your class may not recognize that two instances with same value for `Type` are always equal, regardless of their `Value`.

Answer (score 0):

a bit old fashioned , but it should work , 
If I understand correctrly

```
    Dictionary<string,int> dict=new Dictionary<string,int>();

    //Split accepts 1 character ,assume each line containes key value pair seperated with spaces and not containing whitespaces
    input=input.Replace("\r\n","\n");
    string[] lines=input.Split('\n');

    //break to categories and find largest number at each 
    foreach(line in lines)
    {
        string parts[]=line.Split(' ');
        string key=parts[0].Trim();
        int value=Convert.ToInt32(parts[1].Trim());

        if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dict.Add(key, value);
        }
        else
        {
            if (dict[key]<value)
            {
                    dict[key]=value;
            }
        }

    }


    //do somethig with dict
```