# Get unique elements from a List<String>

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I would like to remove the duplicate elements from a List. Some elements of the list looks like this:

```
Book  23
Book  22
Book  19
Notebook 23
Notebook 22
Notebook 19
Pen 23
Pen 22
Pen 19
```

I would like to keep in the list just

```
Book 23
Notebook 23
Pen 23
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: "What have you tried" would fit well here.

Comment: What is the second column? Are the numbers part of the strings or are they stored in another list?

Comment: Criteria for choosing those particular strings? First of each?

Comment: If they are part of the string then they are already unique.

Comment: whats the output you are getting?

Comment: They are but when you have book 23 and book 22 i would like to keep only book 23 (book 23 and book 22 are unique).

Comment: the output is exactly first example in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove duplicated elements from a List<String>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512385/remove-duplicated-elements-from-a-liststring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about basic looping?

```
List<string> nodup = dup.Distinct().ToList();
List<int> remIndex = new List<int>();
for (int nIdx = 0; nIdx < nodup.Count; nIdx++)
{
    string[] strArr = nodup[nIdx].Split(' ');
    if (String.Compare(strArr[1], "23", true) != 0)
        remIndex.Add(nIdx);
}
foreach (int remIdx in remIndex)
    nodup.RemoveAt(remIdx);
```

Hope this is of some help...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  List<Person> distinctPeople = allPeople
  .GroupBy(p => p.PersonId)
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```

[from this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property)

*use your column names*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list.Sort();
```

`Int32 index = 0;
while (index < list.Count - 1)
{

  if (list[index] == list[index +1])

 list.RemoveAt(index);                                                                  else         index++; }`